# ¿Como refactorizar exceso de condiciones if?

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente bloque de código:

```
data.split('\n').map(l => {
    if (/^videoW/.exec(l)) {
      vidConf.videoW = l.split('=')[1]
    }
    if (/^videoH/.exec(l)) {
      vidConf.videoH = l.split('=')[1]
    }
    if (/^videoT/.exec(l)) {
      vidConf.videoT = l.split('=')[1]
    }
    if (/^videoL/.exec(l)) {
      vidConf.videoL = l.split('=')[1]
    }
    if (/^time=/.exec(l)) {
      vidConf.timeImg = l.split('=')[1]
    }
    if (/^auto=/.exec(l)) {
      vidConf.videoA = l.split('=')[1]
    }
    if (/^typeP=/.exec(l)) {
      vidConf.typeP = l.split('=')[1]
    }

  })
```

Al arreglo **data** lo corto por los saltos de linea(`\n`), porque lo extraigo de un archivo externo y realizo un `map` sobre el para comprobar la existencia de algunas variables en el mediante expresiones regulares y de esta manera pasar los datos a la variable **vidConf**.

¿Como pudiera refactorizar este código evitándome tantas sentencias `if`, y logrando el mismo resultado?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podrías crear un **arreglo con el listado de "casos"** (`eg: ifs`) y luego para cada linea evaluarlos uno por uno.

Podemos usar [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) para evitar controlar todos los casos.

> `some()` ejecuta la función `callback` una vez por cada elemento presente en el `array` hasta que encuentre uno donde `callback` retorna un valor verdadero (true). Si se encuentra dicho elemento, `some()` retorna true inmediatamente.

### Ejemplo:

```js
let data = `videoWeight=18
videoHeight=20
time=200
auto=true`;
let vidConf = {};
let vidProps = [
  {re: /^videoW/, name: 'videoW'},
  {re: /^videoH/, name: 'videoH'},
  {re: /^videoT/, name: 'videoT'},
  {re: /^videoL/, name: 'videoL'},
  {re: /^time$/, name: 'timeImg'},
  {re: /^auto$/, name: 'videoA'},
  {re: /^typeP$/, name: 'typeP'}
]

data.split('\n').map(l => {
  let info = l.split('=');
  let name = info[0];
  let value = info[1];
  
  vidProps.some(prop => {
    if (prop.re.exec(name)) {
      vidConf[prop.name] = value;
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  });
})

console.log(vidConf);
```

Comment: Es más eficiente que un switch?

Comment: @asantanao, podrías crear una respuesta usando `switch` así podemos ver si es más eficiente.