# Script para metadescripcion en javascript

Tags: javascript

tengo un script que me va ajustando la metadesc de cada pagina siempre que se encuentre con su url (por x motivos de mi programacion no me deja cambiar la meta de otra forma), mi pregunta es, tengo mil miniscript para hacer esto segun cada url, aunque sea anidarlos todo en uno para no tener tantas lineas de codigo es posible? Gracias.

Os dejo un ejemplo con solo 3 enlaces, aunque son unos 80. Gracias.

```
<script>
if(window.location.href=="url-1" || window.location.href=="url-1/"){
    var y = document.getElementsByTagName('meta')[3];
    y.setAttribute('content', 'descripción para url 1');
}
</script>
<script>
if(window.location.href=="url-2" || window.location.href=="url-2/"){
    var y = document.getElementsByTagName('meta')[3];
    y.setAttribute('content', 'descripción para url 2');
}
</script>
<script>
if(window.location.href=="url-3" || window.location.href=="url-3/"){
    var y = document.getElementsByTagName('meta')[3];
    y.setAttribute('content', 'descripción para url 3');
}
</script
```

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Como refactorizar exceso de condiciones if?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/126452/como-refactorizar-exceso-de-condiciones-if)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

> **nota:** utilizamos valores negativos en slice ya que el href retorna la url completa.

```
// guardamos la location
let location_ = window.location.href;
// validamos que tenga "/" al final o no y extraemos solo la palabra "url-1"
let url = location_.slice(-1) == "/" ? location_.slice(-6, -1) : location_.slice(-6);
// seleccionamos el meta 3
let meta_ = document.querySelectorAll('meta')[3];
//hacemos un switch
switch (url) {
    case "url-1":
        // si se encuentra extramemos la url y el numero
        meta_.setAttribute('content', `descripción para ${url.slice(-6,-2)} ${url.slice(-1)}`);
        break;
    case "url-2":
        // si se encuentra extramemos la url y el numero
        meta_.setAttribute('content', `descripción para ${url.slice(-6,-2)} ${url.slice(-1)}`);
        break;
    case "url-3":
        // si se encuentra extramemos la url y el numero
        meta_.setAttribute('content', `descripción para ${url.slice(-6,-2)} ${url.slice(-1)}`);
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías limpiar código haciendo un switch:

```
 let url = window.location.href;
   //esto comprueba si tiene la barra al final y la elimina de ser así
    url = url[url.length-1]=="/"?url.slice(0, -1):url;
    switch (url){
      case "url-1":
         var y = document.getElementsByTagName('meta')[3];
         y.setAttribute('content', 'descripción para url 1');
         break;
      case "url-2":
         var y = document.getElementsByTagName('meta')[3];
         y.setAttribute('content', 'descripción para url 2');
         break;
      case "url-3":
         var y = document.getElementsByTagName('meta')[3];
         y.setAttribute('content', 'descripción para url 3');
         break;
    }
```

Y si la variable y la vas a usar siempre y la vas a obtener de la misma forma, creala y asignale el valos antes del switch para ahorrarte 80 líneas.

Un saludo :D

Comment: Gracias! en mi caso las url siempre cargan con / pero comprobaba por si acaso si estaba sin ella

Comment: No me esta entrando a los case, he mirado la url con la que llega justo despues del url = y la devuelve correcta, pero aún así no entra en su case, que puede pasar?